# TikZ standalone document not rendering colour (Overleaf)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, standalone, overleaf

I moved my perfectly fine `tikzpicture` into an external file on its own. But rendering it as a standalone document seems to disregard the `xcolor` package, even though I included that as well.

I'm rendering this on Overleaf with pdfLaTeX, and I have tried switching between the different compilers, although without luck.

```
\documentclass[float=false,crop=true,dvipnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,3d}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={thick,
                               >=stealth,
                               decoration={calligraphic brace,
                                           amplitude=3pt,
                                           raise=4pt}}}

\newcommand\bs[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(10:.9cm)},y={(90:1cm)},z={(-45:.6cm)}]
    \draw [->] (-1,0,0)
            -- ( 0,0,0) coordinate (0_A)
            -- ( 1,0,0) coordinate (P1_A)
            -- ( 2,0,0) coordinate (P2_A)
            -- node[sloped,above=6pt,pos=0,Peach]{$\bs{+}$}
               ( 3,0,0) coordinate (P3_A)
            -- ( 5,0,0) node[right]{};

    \fill (0_A)  circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P1_A) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P2_A) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P3_A) circle (1.5pt);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,Peach]
          (2,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
    \draw [decorate,pen colour={Peach},ultra thick]
          (2,0,0) -- node[sloped,above=6pt,Peach]{$\bs{b}$} (3,0,0);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,RoyalBlue]
          (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0);
    \draw [decorate,pen colour={RoyalBlue},ultra thick]
          (0,0,0) -- node[sloped,above=6pt,RoyalBlue]{$\bs{a}$} (2,0,0);

    \draw (0_A)  circle (2.5pt);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,Gray]
          (0,-.05,0) -- (1,-.05,0);

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \fill [RoyalBlue,opacity=.2] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,0,1) --(0,0,1) -- cycle;

    \draw [->] (-1,0,1)
            -- ( 0,0,1) coordinate (0_B)
            -- ( 1,0,1) coordinate (P1_B)
            -- ( 2,0,1) coordinate (P2_B)
            -- ( 3,0,1) coordinate (P3_B)
            -- ( 5,0,1) node[right]{};

    \fill (0_B)  circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P1_B) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P2_B) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P3_B) circle (1.5pt);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,RoyalBlue]
          (0,0,1) -- (3,0,1);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={mirror},pen colour={RoyalBlue},ultra thick]
          (0,0,1) -- node[sloped,below=4pt,RoyalBlue]{$\bs{\;a'}$} (3,0,1);

    \draw (0_B)  circle (2.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is defined `\bs`?

Comment: In my main document, sorry. But it wouldn't have an influence on the colours – only that my vector names would'nt be bold. Thanks nevertheless :P

Comment: ok, the same result you will obtain with `\documentclass[tikz, dvipsnames]{standalone}`, removing `xcolor`  (it is loaded by `tikz`)  and `tikz` from preamble and after adding `usepackage{bm}` to preamble instead of `\bs` (as shortenes for `\boldsymbol`) use `\bm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me turn my old comment to an answer:

- you need to correct spel color names: instead of `dvipnames` is correct `dvipsnames`
- `the package` xcolor`is loaded by`tikz` package, so you not need to load it again (and eventually have problems with options clash)
- for your `\newcommand\bs[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}` you need to load `amsmath` package. Instead it I would use the `bm` package and comand `\bn{...}`

```
\documentclass[float=false,crop=true,dvipsnames]{standalone} % <--- correct spelling
\usepackage{tikz}  % it load `xcolor` too
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                3d}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={thick,
                               >=stealth,
                               decoration={calligraphic brace,
                                           amplitude=3pt,
                                           raise=4pt}}}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\newcommand\bs[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage{bm} % <--- for use \bm{...} instead of `\bs{...}`,

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(10:.9cm)},y={(90:1cm)},z={(-45:.6cm)}]
    \draw [->] (-1,0,0)
            -- ( 0,0,0) coordinate (0_A)
            -- ( 1,0,0) coordinate (P1_A)
            -- ( 2,0,0) coordinate (P2_A)
            -- node[sloped,above=6pt,pos=0,Peach]{$\bm{+}$}
               ( 3,0,0) coordinate (P3_A)
            -- ( 5,0,0) node[right]{};

    \fill (0_A)  circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P1_A) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P2_A) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P3_A) circle (1.5pt);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,Peach]
          (2,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
    \draw [decorate,pen colour={Peach},ultra thick]
          (2,0,0) -- node[sloped,above=6pt,Peach]{$\bm{b}$} (3,0,0);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,RoyalBlue]
          (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0);
    \draw [decorate,pen colour={RoyalBlue},ultra thick]
          (0,0,0) -- node[sloped,above=6pt,RoyalBlue]{$\bm{a}$} (2,0,0);

    \draw (0_A)  circle (2.5pt);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,Gray]
          (0,-.05,0) -- (1,-.05,0);

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \fill [RoyalBlue,opacity=.2] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,0,1) --(0,0,1) -- cycle;

    \draw [->] (-1,0,1)
            -- ( 0,0,1) coordinate (0_B)
            -- ( 1,0,1) coordinate (P1_B)
            -- ( 2,0,1) coordinate (P2_B)
            -- ( 3,0,1) coordinate (P3_B)
            -- ( 5,0,1) node[right]{};

    \fill (0_B)  circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P1_B) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P2_B) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (P3_B) circle (1.5pt);

    \draw [->,ultra thick,RoyalBlue]
          (0,0,1) -- (3,0,1);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={mirror},pen colour={RoyalBlue},ultra thick]
          (0,0,1) -- node[sloped,below=4pt,RoyalBlue]{$\bm{\;a'}$} (3,0,1);

    \draw (0_B)  circle (2.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I took forever to return to this site. Marked yours as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Providing `dvipsnames` as an option in the `\documentclass` declaration does not seem to be doing the trick. If you provide it directly at the `xcolor` package level, you can use colors like `Peach` etc. i.e. `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`, instead of just `\usepackage{xcolor}`.

Comment: Wait, it worked? - I misspelled `dvipsnames ` as `dvipnames` (without the `s`).

Comment: As it turns out, I could move it back up in the `documentclass` declaration. As long as I spell it correctly! ^^;